# App crashes once Restart Game clicked

Tags: ios, swift, crash

App crashes when either player presses the Restart button. I tried adding an alert that shows up once Player2 accepts game reset and a new alert message that sends to Player1 in the OKAction line.

```
func handleReceivedDataWithNotification(notification:NSNotification){
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo! as Dictionary
    let receivedData:NSData = userInfo["data"] as! NSData

    let message = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(receivedData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
    let senderPeerId:MCPeerID = userInfo["peerID"] as! MCPeerID
    let senderDisplayName = senderPeerId.displayName

    if message.objectForKey("string")?.isEqualToString("New Game") == true{
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Game Restart Request", message: "\(senderDisplayName) has requested to restart the game", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Cancel) { (acttion) in

        }

        alert.addAction(cancelAction)

        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default) { (action) in
            self.resetField()
             let messageDicts = ["string":"RestartNow"]
        }

        alert.addAction(OKAction)

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true) {
        }


    }else{
        var field:Int? = message.objectForKey("field")?.integerValue
        var player:String? = message.objectForKey("player") as? String

        if field != nil && player != nil{
            fields[field!].playerr = player
            fields[field!].setPlayer(player!)

            if player == "x"{
                currentPlayer = "o"
            }else{
                currentPlayer = "x"
            }

            checkResults()

        }

    }
}
```

Here is where the alert is sent to when Player2 presses Accept/Yes:

```
@IBAction func newGame(sender: AnyObject, notification:NSNotification) {

    let alertWait = UIAlertController(title: "Request Sent", message: "Waiting for other player to accept this request", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    self.presentViewController(alertWait, animated: true) {

    }


    let messageDict = ["string":"New Game"]

    let messageData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(messageDict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: nil)

    var error:NSError?

    let userInfo = notification.userInfo! as Dictionary
    let receivedData:NSData = userInfo["data"] as! NSData

    let message = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(receivedData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
    let senderPeerId:MCPeerID = userInfo["peerID"] as! MCPeerID
    let senderDisplayName = senderPeerId.displayName

    if message.objectForKey("string")?.isEqualToString("RestartNow") == true{
        let alertOK = UIAlertController(title: "Game Is Restarting", message: "\(senderDisplayName) has accapted game request", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        let OkayAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (alert:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            self.resetField()
            })

    self.presentViewController(alertOK, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    appDelegate.mpcHandler.session.sendData(messageData, toPeers: appDelegate.mpcHandler.session.connectedPeers, withMode: MCSessionSendDataMode.Reliable, error: &error)

    if error != nil{
        println("error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    } 
}
```

Comment: When the crash occurs, what error is thrown ? And on what line ? It is not possible for us to help you if you do not give us those informations

Comment: @The Tom When the app crashes it pulls up the App Delegate and says sigbart error on the class line.  It doesn't show where the error/crash occurred.